# Why is the HTML helper EditorFor of type file generating multiple file fields in C# and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

View generates 3 file input fields. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screen grab of view]

However, when I add `EditorFor` template for `HttpPostedFileBase`, then it works perfectly. I want to know why is this happening.

This is my model:

```
public class UploadFileViewModel
{
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Select Excel File")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase ExcelFile { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult UploadFileData()
   {
       return View();
   }
}
```

The view:

```
@model DemoProject.Models.UploadFileViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload File Data";
}

<h2>Upload File Data</h2>
<p class="alert-success">@ViewBag.Success</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" });

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">            
            @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.ExcelFile, htmlAttributes: new {@class="control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.ExcelFile, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "file" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExcelFile, new { type = "file" })`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Can't we use Editorfor the way i use in mvc5? I think it should work as I am  passing additionalviewdata (type=file). is this a bug or what? This is the reason i posted this

Comment: No (unless you create an `EditorTemplate` for type of `HttpPostedFileBase`). I'll post an answer shortly explaining the behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Using `EditorFor()` on a complex object generates the default template (which includes a label, form control and validation message placeholder) for each property of the object. `HttpPostedFileBase` contains properties for `ContentType`, `ContentLength` and `FileName` so 3 inputs are generated. Because you have included `type="file"` in the `additionalViewData`, the inputs generated are `type="file"`.

You can simply use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExcelFile, new { type = "file" })
```

or you could create a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `HttpPostedFileBase` so that `EditorFor()` uses that template, rather than the default template. But that template would need to include `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { type = "file" })` so there is probably not much point, other than to include the  `LabelFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` and enclosing `<div>` elements so that all that's needed in the view is `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ExcelFile)` to generate all the html. This can simplify the main view, but the disadvantage is that you cannot for example, have `col-md-10` in one view and `col-md-8` in another.